# How can setTimeout run in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, setinterval

I have two **for loop**, inside them I have **setTimeout** function like following code:

```js
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log(i)}, 1000)
}
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log(i)}, 1000)
}
```

i want the second loop does not executed until after the first loop finished,

```js
I want this result:
0
1
2
0
1
2
- and between 2 numbers wait 1 second.
```

how i can do that?

Comment: PLease see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout i think u need promises on a write function for next part inside the fn that is called by setTimeout

Comment: Why not just increase the delay on the second loop's timeout?

Comment: Then you need to rethink how you are doing this. A queue system would be a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet or I would ask clarifying questions so I'll give you what I think you're asking for. If you want a 1 second delay between each number being logged to the console then this will work:

```
const func = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    await new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i);
        resolve();
      }, 1000)
    );
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    await new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i);
        resolve();
      }, 1000)
    );
  }
};

func();
```

A quick rundown of what's happening here. I created an outer function named `func` which I made asynchronous so that I can use the await keyword within it. I then put the `setTimeout` call inside a new instance of Promise. The promise combined with the await means that javascript will essentially stop at that line until the Promise calls resolve. Once resolve is called that instance of Promise is finished and the await statement stops "blocking" javascript and the callbackque continues.
TLDR:

1. To use await you must be in an asynchronous function.
2. If await is used in front of a Promise everything will stop until the promise resolves.
3. Placing the resolve of the promise inside the callback given to `setTimeout` ensures that we will wait until each timeout finishes BEFORE the next timeout begins.

Comment: If you want something different let me know.

Comment: Since this seems to be what you're looking for I added a quick rundown of what this is doing and why I chose to do it this way. There are many ways to accomplish this that might be clearer in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're trying to do sort of a counter

Try something like this:

```js
for(let i=1;i<=3;i++){
   setTimeout(()=>{ console.log(i)}, i*1000 )
}
```

Let me know if this solve your problem

Comment: not going to give `0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2`

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
nxt (0, 0);//seed the stack
function nxt(num, itertn){
    if(num == 3){//want till 2
        if(itertn == 0){// first or 2nd iteration
            num =0;
            itertn++;
        }else{
            return;//after 2nd stop
        }
    }
    console.log(num);//the work
    num++;    
    setTimeout(nxt, 1000, num, itertn);//next after a second
}
```

But there are other ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try nested loop

```
for(let i=0;i<2;i++){
   for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log(j)}, 1000)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is create `promises`, and with `map` and `promise.all`, you can group each loop of promises and execute them sequentially.

```js
(async () => {
const second = (i) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(i)
  resolve(i)
}, 1000))



const loop = () => Array(3).fill(0).map(async(item, index) => {
  return await second(index)
})

var startTime = performance.now()

await Promise.all(loop())
var endTime = performance.now()
console.log(endTime - startTime)
await Promise.all(loop())
endTime = performance.now()
console.log(endTime - startTime)
})()
```